# Embedding Processing applet in a Swing GUI

Tags: java, swing, applet, processing

The documentation for [Processing PApplet](http://processing.org/reference/javadoc/core/processing/core/PApplet.html) states

> there's nothing to prevent you from embedding a PApplet into a JFrame ...  If people want to use Swing, they can embed themselves as they wish.

However, I did not find any example how to do this, and when I have tried it, the result never worked well - with the code I have now my `PApplet` is embedded, I can even create a menu bar, but the applet does not react to resizing the `JFrame`. Also, the `frame` member of `PApplet` is `null`, therefore any articles I have found (like [this one on Processing forum](http://processing.org/discourse/beta/num_1217592683.html) or [Window Size and Full Screen in the Processing docs](https://github.com/processing/processing/wiki/Window-Size-and-Full-Screen)) regarding this do not work for me.

Here is what I have now, more or less copied from [Using a Processing Sketch as a Java Component](http://www.sebastianoliva.com/en/en/2010/05/using-a-processing-sketch-as-a-java-component/trackback/):

```
import processing.core.PApplet;

public class CurveEditorApplet extends PApplet {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new CurveFrame();
    }
}
```

and

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class CurveFrame extends JFrame {
    CurveFrame() {

        setSize(600, 600);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBounds(20, 20, 600, 600);

        Curve2D sketch = new Curve2D();
        panel.add(sketch);

        add(panel);

        sketch.init();
        sketch.frame = this;

        setVisible(true);

        setResizable(true);
    }
}
```

How can I change it so that the applet is resized when resizing the main window?

Comment: Why are you setting the bounds on your panel? Let the layout manager handle that.

Comment: This was copied from http://www.sebastianoliva.com/en/en/2010/05/using-a-processing-sketch-as-a-java-component/trackback/ - I am not sure leaving it out will make any difference.

Comment: And what happened when you tried leaving it out?

Comment: @YousifAl-Y I am no longer using processing, therefore not really. However, if you can answer the question, it might help other people who have the same problem. I leave the decision to you.